# Is there a way to use the apple SF Symbols on the web

Tags: html, css, sf-symbols

I am trying to make a website and was hoping to use Apple's SF Symbols for some icons, however I can not find a way to get SF Icons onto a website, I downloaded the app and copied the icon however on the website it shows a blank square.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, this application is not permitted by the license that accompanies the SF Symbols download.

> Your use of Symbols obtained from Apple’s SF Font is limited to creating mock-ups of user interfaces for software products running on Apple’s iOS, iPadOS, macOS and tvOS operating systems.

Comment: There is a contradiction in this paragraph above. The font throughout iOS, default for iOS apps, is a variation of SF with different sizes and weights. In addition, a website is something that is viewable on macOS. Why would you create a mockup, but not a production build with SF symbols, if that's indeed the target OS? Then do call out specific use cases that they will reject apps for if you use the symbol incorrectly, for example, the video camera for your own video chat instead of Apple FT. Again, the default font on iOS is not a mockup.

Answer (score 9):

**You are not able to use this icons on the websites as license of SF symbols do not allow use those symbols externally than apple's products.**

## Legal alternative is to use symbols from here:

https://fonts.google.com/icons

https://www.w3schools.com/icons/icons_reference.asp

upd:

https://fontawesome.com/search?m=free&o=r

(most of them are not free, but, link goes to 2,018 free icons)

and by the way you can use it directly from swift using

https://github.com/LiveUI/Awesome

or

https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift

---

### But there exist ways to do this (ILLEGAL ofc)

## way 1

you can try to manually add one of "San Francisco Fonts" to your website and use SFSymbols from those font.

## way 2

you can copy image and paste it to any image editor and save as png.

[image]

After this you can use it as an image on the website. ILLEGALLY.

Comment: Or you can drag and drop into Sketch.app. But absolutely without license.

Comment: @HuuPhongNguyen you're able to do this but this is still not legal to use in websites :)

Answer (score 1):

I copied symbols (UTF8 I guess) from SFSymbols3 mac app into TextEdit and saved it as html.
Resulting page works in Chrome (94.04) on macOS, but surprisingly not in Safari (15.0).

I made a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4so0wzdk/#&togetherjs=Tv12LecGJT

Below a snipped where you have to paste symbol instead XXX and YYY.

```
<style type="text/css">    
   p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 20.0px 'SF Pro'}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p class="p1">XXX 0.circle</p>
  <p class="p1">YYY 00.circle</p>
</body>
</html>
```

SFSymbols3.app from Apple must be installed. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: It doesn't work in Safari because Safari doesn't allow custom installed fonts to prevent user fingerprinting by list of installed fonts.